# Neo4j logging in a server extension while running from within a JUnit test in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, logging, intellij-idea, junit, neo4j

I am using Neo4j 3.2.1 community edition and IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2017.1 with JUnit 4.12 and Java 8.

I get the `org.neo4j.logging.Log` object in the procedure class using:

```
@Context
public Log log;
```

and then am using it in the methods:

```
log.info("Info message...");
```

This works just fine when running neo4j and calling the extension, but the logs are not visible when running from inside Intellij using the server instance created in the JUnit test.

My test code looks like this:

```
package graphEngine;

import GraphComponents.TestGraphQueries;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.neo4j.driver.v1.Config;
import org.neo4j.driver.v1.Driver;
import org.neo4j.driver.v1.GraphDatabase;
import org.neo4j.driver.v1.Session;
import org.neo4j.harness.junit.Neo4jRule;

public class ComputeTest {

    @Rule
    public Neo4jRule neo4j = new Neo4jRule()
            .withProcedure(Compute.class)
            .withProcedure(TestGraphQueries.class);

    @Test
    public void shouldFindMatchingSystems() throws Throwable {
        try(Driver driver = GraphDatabase.driver( neo4j.boltURI() , Config.build()
                .withEncryptionLevel( Config.EncryptionLevel.NONE ).toConfig() );

            Session session = driver.session() ) {

            session.run("CALL graphEngine.loadGraph");

            session.run("CALL graphEngine.compute(8)");

        }
    }

}
```

The log file seems to go to a directory where the server instance is run that is created during execution but then is deleted immediately after.

Is there a way I can set the location for the log file and see the logs printed to the IntelliJ run/debug console?

Answer (score 2):

I'd the same issue (Visual Studio Code / Maven / Neo4J CE 3.2.0) and solved it with the following workaround:

Define the folder, in that the neo4j-server instance must be run and set as rule configuration items the paths for log- and run-directories:

```
public class TestClass {
...
private static final String basePath = "C:\\Development\\myworkspaces\\myproject\\run";

private static final String serverPath = basePath + "\\neo4j";

private static final String logsPath = basePath + "\\logs";

...

@Rule
public Neo4jRule neo4j = new Neo4jRule(
                              new File(
                                TestClass.serverPath
                              )
                           )
  ...
  .withConfig("dbms.directories.logs", TestClass.logsPath)
  .withConfig("dbms.directories.run", TestClass.basePath)
  .withConfig("dbms.logs.debug.level", "DEBUG")
  ...
```

Implement a method to backup the log data in the current server instance (after each test method in the class):

```
@After
public void backupLogMessages() {
File serverFolder = new File(serverPath);
Arrays.stream(serverFolder.listFiles())
  .filter(f -> f.isDirectory())
    .forEach(d -> 
    {
        Optional<File> logFile = 
          Arrays.stream(d.listFiles())
            .filter(fnd -> !fnd.isDirectory())
            .filter(ff -> ff.getName().indexOf("neo4j") != -1)
            .findFirst();
        logFile.ifPresent(lf -> 
        {
          String parentFolderName 
            = lf.getParent()
              .substring(lf.getParent().lastIndexOf("\\")+1);
          Path logPath 
            = FileSystems
              .getDefault()
              .getPath(TestClass.logsPath);
          String absolutePath 
            = logPath
              .toAbsolutePath().toString();
          try {
            FileUtils.copyFile(
              lf, 
              new File(absolutePath 
                + "\\" + parentFolderName 
                + "_neo4j.log")
            );
          } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
          }
  });
});
}
```

This method localizes the folder of the neo4j instance (as subfolder of the 'serverPath') and looks for the neo4j.log file in that. If a such file exists, it will be copied to the logs-folder with another filename.

In my opinion it must exist a more elegant solution, but I've not yet found it.

Comment: Not quite the elegant solution I was hoping for, but will do the trick for now. Thanks!!!